# Is alms-giving (giving charity) to the addict people permissible? (Shi'a view)

Tags: shiism, sadaqah, tradition

Giving Sadaghah (alms-giving) is a Mustahab (recommended) act in Islam and according to the traditions it has so thawab (reward).

For instance, look at the following hadith from the Prophet (pbuh) regarding Alms.

The apostle of Allah (pbuh) said:

> The alms(al-Sadaghah) will remove the plagues (Aafaat) from its owner
>   and removes the torture of the day judgment.
>
> Bahar al-Anwar, Vol.96, Pg.129.
>
> ---
>
> Or likewise there are so many other traditions which point out the
>   rewards of almsgiving.

But I was wondering if it is permissible to give alms to the addicts? And likewise if Allah will give us all of its thawabs which mentioned in many traditions in the case that we give it to the addicts as poor people?

*(I inquired this question because we can guess (not sure) that addict people will waste their money to buy narcotic substances..)*

Answer (score -1):

**We ought not to give the alms to the person who is addict. (Since commonly they expend the money for their drugs), so, because the use of the drugs is one of Great-Sins (1), so it would be a sin to give the alms (as helping) to them.
Since the holy Qur'an says that**

> We ought not to help in the ways of sins...(2)

(1): Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi, Estefta'at, Vol.2, Question number 748.

(2): Surah Al-Ma'ida : 2

---

**Sources**:

- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/5:2)
- [http://raz.ahlolbait.com](http://raz.ahlolbait.com/content)

Comment: I'd add that you can get around this by using things like food vouchers.